# Hybris cron job manual start ingores nodeGroup settings

Tags: triggers, cron, sap-commerce-cloud

In our application if we start a cron job manually from the BO, it ignores the already set nodeGroup and instead it starts on the current server node. (If it is triggered by a time based trigger it starts correctly on the set nodeGroup.)
Is it on purpose or is it a bug? Are we missing something?
Hybris version is 5.7.

Answer (score 2):

I would expect it to work like that since you have chosen the node by opening its backoffice. You could also choose the node you want to run the cronjob on by accessing its backoffice. Which node you access depends on the URL you enter.

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to work like that since what if we have dedicated BO servers used by our clients employees? In that case they have no possiblility to reach the job-servers, this way they are not able to specify the "correct" node.
But I'm not here to argue about it, I only would like to figure out if it is a bug or not. 
Thx for the reply!

Comment: I don't think there is a right or wrong on this topic. But it is an interesting question.

Comment: "Which node you access depends on the URL you enter." -- If they use a load balancer, the node will be random, unless they know the IP/address for the specific node.

Comment: Point taken, but if they use dedicated BO servers, they should also be able to access the jobs servers directly.